# Create a dynamic title + subtitle using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using the following code to create a ggplot graph with title and substitle:

This is the code for generating the dataframe

```
t <- c(1.4,2.1,3.4)
time <- c(10,11,12)
df_match <- data.frame(t, time)
```

And this is the code for generating the plot.

```
g <- ggplot(df_match, aes(time, t)) + geom_point()
g + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) + ggtitle(expression(atop("Head", atop(italic("Location"), ""))))
```

This works fine. However, when I want to create a dynamic chart and I do:

```
title <- "Dynamic"
```

And this:

```
g <- ggplot(df_match, aes(time, t)) + geom_point()
g + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) + ggtitle(expression(atop(title, atop(italic("Location"), ""))))
```

I get "title" as title in stead of "Dynamic". Any thoughts on what goes wrong here?

Comment: This works for me: `title <- "iris"; ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Width,y=Sepal.Length)) + geom_point() + labs(title = title)`

Comment: Thanks, but I also need a subtitle... Any thoughts?>

Comment: If you install the dev version from github (or wait a bit for it's official release) there is new official (easy) support for subtitle: https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/09/30/ggplot2-2-2-0-coming-soon/

Comment: `g + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) + ggtitle(title, subtitle = "location")` works for me. Edit: I do have the dev version which is to be released soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `bquote` to evaluate the bits you need evaluated. Put the objects you want evaluated in `.()`

`g + ggtitle(bquote(atop(.(title), atop(italic("Location"), ""))))`

Answer (score 1):

Using `g` and `title` from the question, try `substitute`:

```
g + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) + 
    ggtitle(substitute(atop(title, atop(italic("Location"), "")), list(title = title)))
```

giving:

[image]