# In ggplot, how to set plot title as x variable choosed when using a function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a function that when I choose the variables it plots me a ggplot.

It works well.

```
gg_f <- function(df, var_x){

  ggplot(df, aes(x = {{var_x}}, mpg)) + geom_point()

}

gg_f(df = mtcars, var_x = cyl)
```

But when I tried to set the plot title as the `var_x` variable that I choose I have problems.

I tried o use `glue` but it didnt work:

```
gg_f <- function(df, var_x){
    
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = {{var_x}}, mpg)) + geom_point() + labs(title = glue::glue({var_x})
    
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: [See if this Q & A helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39960992/create-a-dynamic-title-subtitle-using-ggplot2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `substitute(var_x)`

```r
library(ggplot2)

gg_f <- function(df, var_x){

  ggplot(df, aes(x = {{var_x}}, mpg)) + 
    geom_point() +
    labs(title = substitute(var_x))

}

gg_f(df = mtcars, var_x = cyl)
```

[image]

Or `rlang::englue`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

gg_f <- function(df, var_x){

  ggplot(df, aes(x = {{var_x}}, mpg)) + 
    geom_point() +
    labs(title = rlang::englue("{{var_x}}"))

}

gg_f(df = mtcars, var_x = cyl)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I suppose the `rlang` version is `labs(title = as_name(enquo(var_x)))`.

Comment: @Axeman or `rlang::englue`

Comment: @AllanCameron if I want to use "outside" my function? Something like: `gg_f(df = mtcars, var_x = cyl) + labs(......)`

Comment: @Laura why wouldn't you just put `labs(title = "cyl")` if it was outside your function?

Comment: `rlang::englue`. That's nice. I think, I need a deep dive into `rlang`.

Comment: @AllanCameron my original function is much bigger than this one.

Comment: @Laura but if you put 'labs()` outside your function, you have no way to pass arguments to it other than specifying them directly.